# Adding greek character to axis title

Tags: r, unicode, label, plotmath

I want to add a greek character to the y-axis of my barplot in R.
The problem is that I need this character to be integrated in the title. I want to write:

```
Diameter of aperture ("mu"m)
```

in the axis label.

With

```
ylab=expression()
```

I can write the greek character, with

```
ylab="axis title"
```

I can write the title with proper spaces between the words.

But I can't find a way to put all these together and write a proper label with a greek word in the axis label. I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you're using `plotmath{grDevices}`, the main help page ([plotmath](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html)) contains an example of what you appear to want:

```
xlab = expression(paste("Phase Angle ", phi))
```

or for your case, I guess:

```
ylab = expression(paste("Diameter of aperture ( ", mu, " )"))
```

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 45):

I think I followed your question properly. The `~` forces a space between characters in a call to `expression()`. Is this what you want?

```
plot(1:3, ylab = expression("Diameter of apeture (" * mu ~ "m)"),
  , xlab = expression("Force spaces with ~" ~ mu ~ pi * sigma ~ pi)
  , main = expression("This is another Greek character with space" ~ sigma))
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

And if you want to substitute variables in the text, use `bquote`. For instance, if you have a variable `mu` and want to show it in the title, then use the following idiom:

```
mu <- 2.8
plot(1:3, main=bquote(mu == .(mu)))
```

The part enclosed in `.()` will be substituted, so that the value of `mu` will be printed and not the greek "mu" character. Consult the R help on `bquote` for details.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This should be much more straight forward with `latex2exp`:

```
require(latex2exp)
plot(1, xlab = TeX('$\\mu$'))
```

Comment: This is so much more useable than expression if you are used to typesetting with Latex. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

And, in case you were dealing with an estimated quantity, `plotmath{grDevices}` also offers the possibility of adding a hat to your greek letter:

```R
ylab = expression(paste("Diameter of aperture ( ", hat(mu), " )"))
```

The `mu` enclosed in `hat()` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I give an updated answer to Chase's plot example (from 2011) above while working with Windows 10 with a suitable TrueType Font with the help package utf8 on R 3.62. 
In my answer, I assign a value to μ. The unicode characters I just call out by their hex (??) code. The space is just a 'space' inside quotes. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105619/insert-specific-unicode-symbols-inside-values-of-data-frame-variable/59763650#59763650):

See also:
http://www.unicode.org/Public/10.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt

[utf8-package {utf8}](https://cran.r-project.org/package=utf8)

```
# pi small case
utf8_print("\u03C0")
"π"
# sigma small case
utf8_print("\u03C3")
"σ"

μ <- abs(digamma(1))
μseq <- seq(μ,3*μ,μ)
dev.new()
plot(μseq, ylab = "Diameter of apeture ( μ m)",
  , xlab = "Force spaces with ~ μ  \u03C0  \u03C3  \u03C0 ",
  , main = "This is another Greek character with space \u03C3")
#
```

[image]