# Adding greek characters with variables to axis title

Tags: r, plot, label, plotmath

I have two vectors `alpha <- c(1,2,3)`, `beta <- c(4,5,6)`. I have three plots and each of them is using diferent `alpha` and `beta` (etc. first plot contains `alpha[1]` and `beta[1]`)

Now I would like to add axis title to each graph like: `"alpha = 1, beta = 4"` with greek letters. How can I do it? I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044800/adding-greek-character-to-axis-title) so I tried some solutions from there, but:

with `bquote()` I can use only one `=` . So I can do

`bquote(alpha == .(alpha[1]) * ", " * beta * .(beta[1]))` do get `alpha = 1, beta4`

but I can't add another `=`

with `expression(paste())` variables works like text, so instead of `alpha = 1`, I got 
`alpha = alpha[1]`

What is a correct way how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try using a plotmath `list` call:

```
plot(1,1, main= bquote(list( alpha == .(alpha[1]) ,  beta == .(beta[1])) )  )
```

Comment: Thanks to @user3502164 for trying to fix my error. I don't agree with the first reviewer. Since I also noticed the error and applied the same fix, I thought it was needed. The rationale that an edit must be "significant" means that even deleting a single "=" sign will be "significant" if it creates working code where erroneous code was offered before.