# How to add Greek characters in R

Tags: r, character

How can I add Greek letters in R? When I am typing at Greek, doesn't understand the characters, for example I tried to type "κ" which is the Greek "k", but R shows "?". Thanks :)

Comment: Where are you trying to display these greek letters?
This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044800/adding-greek-character-to-axis-title

Comment: Hard to know whether you have the correct locale settings and the associated fonts that should support them. See `?Sys.setlocale` and tell us the results of `Sys.getlocale()`