# Getting greek character in plot axis

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I am making barplots for different metal concentration in various materials, and need the axis to say **μg/g**. I've searched for how to implement greek characters into different plots, but I don't seem able to actually do so. It looks like I should be able to use (`expression(paste)`) - can anyone help me?

This is an extract of my current script:

```
BP.Ag <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Material, y=Ag, fill=Sample.Material)) +  
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + ylab("Silver (μg/g)") + guides(fill=FALSE) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the UTF-8 for µ ("\u00B5"):

```
>cat("\u00B5")
µ
```

In your plot you could use:

```
ylab("Silver (\u00B5g/g)")
```

Answer (score -1):

A similar question was asked here: [Adding greek character to axis title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044800/adding-greek-character-to-axis-title)

Your ylab should be something like `+ylab(expression(paste("Silver ", mu,"g/g")))`