# How to use Greeks together with alphabets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Very close to this question [How to use Greek symbols in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293715/1568919), but I don't just want a single greek letter, I want something like `Δprice` as a label.

To get Δ as my xlabel, I can use `xlab(expression(Delta))`, but how to get Δprice?

Comment: Study `help("plotmath")`. `expression(Delta * "price")`

Comment: Also today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112094/getting-greek-character-in-plot-axis